# How do I get the label from a selected checkbox?

Tags: lightning-web-components, checkbox, inputcheckboxes, fieldservice, lightning-checkbox-group

It's a lightning web component.

**event.detail.label** doesn't work and **event.detail.value** only gives me the value.

Can someone help please?

Comment: what does the markup of your lightning web component look like?

Comment: @glls
We can use the checkbox group example, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-checkbox-group/example

but instead of the value, I want the label.

Comment: Linked to related answers. Basically, you need to find the labels based on the value from the original list. This is the exact same behavior you'd except in plain JavaScript, jQuery, etc.